# Flex Map component, update extent on resize

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex

I have application with Flex Map component. Application has several states, and map component's size is changed depending on states. When state is changed, I need to change extent. But for some reasons, map component is not recalculated by that time. I tried to change extent on resize event. I see in debug mode, that map width is changed, but when I try to set new extent, it "thinks" that map width is not changed yet. So, every time I set new Extent, it's set for the previous map state width. I tried callLater, but all the same, map component has not calculated something inside itself and sets extent for the previous map width. Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

Using a modified example of the [EventBasics API sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-samples-flex/blob/develop/web/src/EventBasics.mxml), I get the following event order after a state changes the size of the Map component:

1. resize
2. updateComplete
3. extentChange
4. updateComplete

Try waiting for the extentChange that happen after the resize.